# DrupalPro on VirtualBox is not displaying properly

Tags: drupal, windows-8.1, virtualbox

I just downloaded DrupalPro onto Oracle VM VirtualBox. When I first boot up the guest OS everything is displayed normally (the boot up screens appear as they should) but once the boot up is complete the DrupalPro desktop screen is all white. When I move my mouse over certain parts of the screen fragments of the desktop will begin to appear but then go away as the mouse continues to move. When I switched to full screen view the entire desktop appeared and looked normal but as soon as I began moving the cursor around the view would go back to displaying bits and pieces of the screen.

Is this a problem with my resolution or another one of my settings?

I'm using Windows 8.1 as my host OS (64-bit OS), Virtual Box 4.3.14 for Windows, and DrupalPro Beta2 32-bit. If it matters my graphics card is well above average but doesn't peak the top of the line.

[image]

Update:

I went into the settings on the VirtualBox for the DrupalPro VM and I turned the video memory all the way up. Now sometimes it will display perfectly fine, but every once in a while when I start p I'll get the original problem as shown in the picture here.

Answer (score 1):

I did this as well and it helped. I also unchecked the Enable 3D Acceleration checkbox in the Display tab under Settings. That fixed it for me. I'm windows 8.1 with a newer machine as well.

Comment: I'm on a new machine as well with Windows 8.1. I'll try this out, but I ended up going with Aquia and some pre-built beginner set up. I haven't worked on Drupal since my Fall semester started though, thanks for the tip, once I test it out and it works I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also on windows 8.1. I had a memory problem when loading Drupal Pro. Everything was working perfectly fine if I had it installed on virtualbox 4.3.4, but the latest version has made it act funny. By removing the 3d acceleration everything seems to be working.